# Error in TestNG Test execution in parallel

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am getting "
Failed to create file" error in console log when running testng test cases in parallel. Am i missing something or do i need to add something in pom.xml ?

Something like below error is observed:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\askha2\git\sxyz.test\Copy of mnopqrst.xml

Test case: tigermania

Test case: applemania 

Test case: potatomania

Failed to create file
Failed to create file
XML URL: JOB ...
```

My xml file looks something like this as shown below :

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="DEV XYZ Service Smoke Test Suite"
allow-return-values="true" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

<test name="Test Context URL - 1">
    <parameter name="sUrl" value="JOB" />
    <classes>
        <class
            name="com.abc.tigermania"></class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="Test Context URL - 2">
    <parameter name="sUrl" value="JOB" />
    <classes>
        <class
            name="com.abc.applemania"></class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="Test Context URL - 3">
    <parameter name="sUrl" value="JOB" />
    <classes>
        <class
            name="com.abc.potatomania"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

I also see more failures when i increase thread-count="2"

Comment: how are you executing the tests and also could you share the entire error log please.

Comment: am executing using run->run configuration

Comment: please share ethe complete logs as well. the question is still unclear